# Woman fights man with "blue" super powers

Tags: story-identification, comics

The comic starts with this guy and a woman kissing, then his girlfriend or wife comes and catches them in the act. She starts fighting the guy with superpowers (her powers are blue and look cool as heck) and then at the end of the fight after killing the guy, she transforms into this phoenix type form (similar appearance to Phoenix from X-Men)  and flies away. She had blue hair. Read it in 2003 -2004 give or take, it's comic like and it was drawn in color. I think it's target audience leaned more towards adults. Anybody have a clue? It's been driving me kinda crazy. That’s all I remember but the graphics of the comic looked futuristic.

Comment: When did you read this comic ? How old was it? What language was it in? Can you remember anything more about it? Any little detail might help us to identify it!

Comment: 2003 -2004 give or take, comic like and it was in color. I think it's target audience leaned more towards adults. Anybody have a clue? It's been driving me kinda crazy.

Comment: [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/141540/edit) that in and see if anyone responds

Comment: Sounds like some Heavy Metal comics. I used to love those. Comics with full nudity and full of gore. Cant remember reading that perticular one tho. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d3/93/af/d393afcf6f6f39e16118af31327e9b7f.jpg

Comment: You're onto something there. They're called heavy metal?